huitième, dixième classe : équivalent moderne ?
Je lis dans un célèbre extrait des Mots (1963) de Jean-Paul Sartre (1905-1980) :

«Le proviseur donna les mains à tout : on me fit entrer en huitième et
je pus croire que j’allais fréquenter des enfants de mon âge. Mais non
: après la première dictée, mon grand-père fut convoqué en hâte par
l’administration ; il revint enragé, tira de sa serviette un méchant
papier couvert de gribouillis, de taches et le jeta sur la table :
c’était la copie que j’avais remise. On avait attiré son attention sur
l’orthographe – « le lapen çovache aime le ten », – et tenté de lui
faire comprendre que ma place était en dixième préparatoire.»

Je cherche un document en ligne expliquant à quoi correspondent la classe de huitième(=CM1 ?) et de dixième préparatoire(=CE1 ?).
La consultation de ces deux articles(celui-ci et celui-là) ne m'a pas permis d'en savoir plus.
Merci d'avance !

Oui, la huitième correspond bien au CM1 et la dixième au CE1.
La logique de numérotation inversée peut se poursuivre jusqu'au cours préparatoire qui correspond donc à la onzième.
Ce système est encore en usage dans des établissement d'enseignement privé en France.

Huitième (TLFi)
[...]

En particulier [Par ellipse de classe; dans un établissement scolaire ayant des classes primaires et secondaires] Huitième classe avant les classes terminales, quatrième année de l'enseignement primaire. Depuis les grands jusqu'aux petits, depuis les élèves de philosophie jusqu'aux élèves de huitième (Champfl., Souffr. profess. Delteil, 1855, p. 18). Je ne cherche plus à comprendre pour quelles raisons ma mère, quand je commençai ma huitième, me mit pensionnaire (Gide, Si le grain, 1924, p. 407).


